# Find String and then apply formatting to preceding number of characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a large document in word, around 800 pages, which I need to apply some formating after finding a person's name within the text.

The text will look like the below.

01/01/1999, 09:00 - Joe Bloggs:

I want to find "Joe Bloggs" in the entire document and then apply formatting to make it bold and Tahoma font to not only the name but the date and time before the name which I believe is 20 characters.

Can anybody help with what may be a simple problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for what you described (Joe Bloggs: and move 20 characters to the left).

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim oRng As Range
With Selection
    '''move selectiont to start of document
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With .Find
        .Text = "Joe Bloggs:"
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        Do While .Execute
            Set oRng = Selection.Range
            With oRng
                .MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-20
                .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
            End With
            Selection.MoveRight
        Loop
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using Find/Replace in Word (no VBA) you can

0. Open `Find/Replace`
1. Click the `More` button to expose the `Use Wildcards` option
2. Select the `Use Wildcards` option
3. For `Find What` enter `([!¤]{20,20}Joe Bloggs)`
4. For `Replace with` enter `\1` then click the `Format` button to change to **Bold Tahoma**. You should see `Tahoma, bold` below the replace box.
5. Now do normal `Find Next`, `Replace`, `Replace All` as you see fit.

Note: the `¤` character in the `Find What` search can be any character you're sure is **NOT** in your target text.

Comment: Agreed. VBA is wholly unnecessary for this. If you omit the outer pair of brackets you can use  `^&` as the replace text, which can also be found by clicking the Special button and selecting "Find what text" from the context menu.